# fuzzy search in full text search

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, fuzzy-search, trigram, misspelling

I'm using postgresql to Full Text Search and I am finding that users will not receive results if there are misspellings.I want to use fuzzy search and full text search together.For example  I could not  combine Trigram indexes and full text search.

What is the best way to handle misspelt words in Postgres full text search?

Comment: Why do you want to use full text search if trigram indexes do the trick?

Comment: I have product table and I want to search  for 'personel pen' . When I write 'prsonel pen' or 'persnel pn'.., I want to find the 'personal pen' product.

Comment: You can do that with a trigram index without using full text search, right?

Comment: Yes I can use only trigram index but if i do this ,I just can not find the pen.

Comment: Why not? Can you explain in some more detail?

Comment: select * from product  where  katadi % 'pencil '  ->is working but 
select * from product  where  katadi % 'pncil ' -> not working 

select * from product  where  katadi % 'prsnel pen'    -> not working 
select * from product  where  katadi % ' pen'     -> not working
select * from product  where  katadi % ' pers'     -> not working

Comment: Lower `pg_trgm.similarity_threshold`, or better search like this: `SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY katadi <-> ' pen' LIMIT 10`.

Comment: When I wrote it in this way, it worked, would you suggest a source of how to use it in laravel?
thank you so much

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that you either use full-text search or trigram similarity matching, but don't try to mix them.

Based on the requirement, I would say that trigram similarity matching is the better fit.

If you don't get a result using the similarity operator `%`, you have two choices:

1. Lower the similarity threshold `pg_trgm.similarity_threshold`.
2. Query in a different way so that you get the best matches, however „distant” they are:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY katadi <-> ' pen' LIMIT 10;
   ```

   I think that would be the better solution.

Comment: Can I use this to search for more than one table? For example katadi and product_quality in diffrent table

Comment: You can use two statements or use `UNION` to combine two queries into one result.

Answer (score -1):

To use fuzzy search you need to ensure the extension is present.

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS fuzzystrmatch;
```

Check the documentation, but you apply the search like;

```
SELECT levenshtein('GUMBO', 'GAMBOL');
```

You could put the result into a column to order by perhaps? You should also investigate "regexp_replace" to fix some of your known misspellings